# How to display data using a namespaced controller rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have an admin namespace with items as a resource in it:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :items
end
```

My items controller located in *app/controllers/admin/* looks like this:

```
module Admin
  class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    def show             
    end

    private

    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

The problem I have is displaying the data in a show view: admin/items#show

it seems like since I have an admin namespace I cant display the data like I used to before I started trying out namespaces and scopes.

```
<p>
  <strong>Tittle:</strong>
  <%= @item.tittle %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Desciption:</strong>
  <%= @item.description %>
</p>

<!-- More item attributes -->
```

There error I get is:

```
undefined method `tittle' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Why is `@item` nil? And, what are `tittle` and `Desciption`?

Answer (score 0):

Your show method does not set `@item` to anything.

Try

```
def show
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a method `set_item` defined in your controller, but you haven't called it anywhere for your `show` action. Add a `before_action` like below:

```
module Admin
  class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_item, only: [:show]

    def show             
    end

    private

    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren’t calling `set_item` anywhere. Either call that method directly in the show method, or call it in a before action by putting the following above the show method

```
before_action :set_item, only: :show
```